# disable rSpec's auto generated test files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

Does anyone know how to disable rspec's auto generated test files on creation of a rails resource ?

I find that I usually clean out most of the default code and would rather start from a clean file every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option #1: If you don't want to generate spec files at all

Add this to your `application.rb` file:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.controller_specs false
  g.view_specs false
  g.helper_specs false
  g.routing_specs false
end
```

### Option #2: If you don't want to generate spec for a specific generator

```
rails g scaffold Foo bar:string --no-helper-specs --no-view-specs
```